# How to add values to datagridcombobxcolumn?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, combobox, datagrid, entity

I have a datagrid in that I have two columns month(values: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 1112and month type(values 1, 2, 3) quarters.
How to add values to the month type combobox  to select?

In my data entity month type is defined as

Public byte MonthTypes;

Answer (score 0):

You can use a DataGridComboBoxColumn in your DataGrid and set the ItemsSource to the list of you values.

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="My header"
                        SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfValues}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that this is your model:

```
public class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    int _quarter;
    public int Quarter { get { return _quarter; } set { _quarter = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Quarter"); } }

    int _month;
    public int Month { get { return _month; } set { _month = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Month"); } }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    internal void RaisePropertyChanged(string propname)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propname));
    }
}
```

and there is an observablecollection in the view model

```
    ObservableCollection<Model> _models;
    public ObservableCollection<Model> Models { get { return _models; } set { _models = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Models"); } }
```

You can use the `DataGridTemplateColumn`, similar to the following Xaml:

```
 <DataGrid DataContext="{Binding}" ItemsSource="{Binding Models}"  AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding Month, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                        <sys:Int32>1</sys:Int32>
                        <sys:Int32>2</sys:Int32>
                        <sys:Int32>3</sys:Int32>
                        <sys:Int32>4</sys:Int32>
                        <sys:Int32>5</sys:Int32>
                        <sys:Int32>6</sys:Int32>
                        <sys:Int32>7</sys:Int32>
                        <sys:Int32>8</sys:Int32>
                        <sys:Int32>9</sys:Int32>
                        <sys:Int32>10</sys:Int32>
                        <sys:Int32>11</sys:Int32>
                        <sys:Int32>12</sys:Int32>
                    </ComboBox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding Quarter, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                        <sys:Int32>1</sys:Int32>
                        <sys:Int32>2</sys:Int32>
                        <sys:Int32>3</sys:Int32>
                        <sys:Int32>4</sys:Int32> 
                    </ComboBox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

don't forget:

```
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

Of course note that you can bind the ComboBox ItemsSource to an Enum, too.